# Hibernate connection provider issue

Tags: hibernate, jboss

We are facing a strange issue.

We are having a web application with spring and hibernate persistence. We are facing issue while deploying our application on Jboss with below error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate connection provider [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.TransactionAwareDataSourceConnectionProvider]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:192) [hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:114) [hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:54) [hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:69) [hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:176) [hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.TransactionAwareDataSourceConnectionProvider cannot be cast to org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:189) [hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
    ... 41 more
```

Looks like it is conflicting with existing jar in jboss. SAme setup is working fine in windows but not working in linux server.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Hibernate 4.1.9 with classes from the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3` package. You shouldn't. Classes in this package must be used with Hibernate 3.x. To use Hibernate 4 with Spring, use classes from the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4`package.

Comment: But this is working fine in windows environment. We are facing issue when we are trying to deploy on linux server